# Mysql query UNION with ORDER don't work

Tags: mysql, sql, union, union-all

I've a problem with my sql query.

This code is for show articles that have a day of publication.

example:

```
BLOG ONE: day of pubblication every 16th of mounth
BLOG TWO: day of pubblication every 2nd of mounth
BLOG THREE: day of pubblication every 23th of mounth
```

So today 24th i must see blog with day of publication 24,25,26,27,28,1,2,3,4,5.................

the problem is to merge two queries

```
( DAY FROM TODAY TO 31th) + (DAY FROM 1st TO YESTERDAY)
```

THIS IS THE FIRST QUERY

```
$queryallblog = mysql_query("
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM day,blog 
  WHERE day.autore = blog.titolo && day.titolo >= DAY(CURRENT_DATE())
  ORDER BY day.titolo
)") or die(" Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());
```

and this is the second:

```
$queryallblog = mysql_query("
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM day,blog 
  WHERE day.autore = blog.titolo && day.titolo < DAY(CURRENT_DATE())
  ORDER BY day.titolo
)") or die(" Error: (" . mysql_errno() . ") " . mysql_error());
```

WITH THE UNION STATEMENT the global order is not correct

Comment: Where is your query with Union?

Comment: Show us your `UNION ALL` statement!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your problem is not about an UNION query but it's about sorting correctly the results. I would use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  day inner join blog on day.autore = blog.titolo
ORDER BY
  case when day.titolo >= DAY(CURRENT_DATE()) then 1 else 2 end,
  day.titolo
```

- I'm using an inner join instead of the where syntax
- case when will return 1 when day.titolo is >= the current day, and 2 otherwise. First will be returned rows after the current day, then the rows before the current day
- I'm then ordering rows by day.titolo
- You probably need to add other filters e.g. the month

You can obtain a similar result with an UNION ALL query but you have to add an extra column:

```
SELECT 1 as t, *
FROM day inner join blog on day.autore = blog.titolo
WHERE day.titolo >= DAY(CURRENT_DATE())
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as t, *
FROM day inner join blog on day.autore = blog.titolo
WHERE day.titolo < DAY(CURRENT_DATE())
ORDER BY t, day.titolo
```

However I would not reccomend it, at least not on this context.

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT * 

FROM day,blog 
WHERE day.autore = blog.titolo && day.titolo >= DAY(CURRENT_DATE())
ORDER BY day.titolo) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT * 

FROM day,blog 
WHERE day.autore = blog.titolo && day.titolo < DAY(CURRENT_DATE())
ORDER BY day.titolo)
```